# How To Retrieve place_ID from Google Maps address_component

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I would like to obtain the Google Maps `place_id` from the address components however I am not sure if it is possible. I currently have the following code:

```
// Extract From Address Function
function extractFromAddress(components, type){
    for (var i=0; i<components.length; i++)
        for (var j=0; j<components[i].types.length; j++)
            if (components[i].types[j]==type) return components[i].long_name;
    return "";
}

// Variables
var varMap, varMapOptions, varMapDefaultLatLng, varInput, varAutocompleteOptions;
var varDefaultBounds, varAutocomplete, varMarker, varPlace, varInfoWindow, varInfoWindowContent;
var varPlaceID, varPlaceTitle, varPlaceACSZ;
var varInputText, varInputLength;

// Map Listener
google.maps.event.addListener(varAutocomplete, "place_changed", function() {
    // Set Map
    varInfoWindow.close();
    varMarker.setVisible(false);                        
    // Autocomplete
    varPlace = varAutocomplete.getPlace();

    // Check for geometry
    if (!varPlace.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (varPlace.geometry.viewport) {
        varMap.fitBounds(varPlace.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
        varMap.setCenter(varPlace.geometry.location);
        varMap.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }

    // Set Marker Icon
    google.maps.event.addListener(varMap, "click", function(event) {
        varMarker.setPosition(event.latLng);
    });

    // Marker Position
    varMarker.setPosition(varPlace.geometry.location);
    varMarker.setVisible(true);

    // Obtain Address Components
    if (varPlace.address_components) {
        var varPlaceID = extractFromAddress(varPlace.address_components, "place_id");  // Currently doesn't return a value
        var varStreetNumbers = extractFromAddress(varPlace.address_components, "street_number");
        var varStreetName = extractFromAddress(varPlace.address_components, "route");
        var varCity = extractFromAddress(varPlace.address_components, "locality");
        var varState = extractFromAddress(varPlace.address_components, "administrative_area_level_1");
        var varPostCode = extractFromAddress(varPlace.address_components, "postal_code");
    }

    // Assign Address Components
    varGooglePlaceID = varPlaceID;
    varPlaceTitle = varPlace.name;
    varPlaceAddress = varStreetNumbers + ' ' + varStreetName;
    varPlaceACSZ = varPlaceAddress + '<br>' + varCity + ', ' + varState + ' ' + varPostCode;
    varPlaceLatitude = varPlace.geometry.location.lat();
    varPlaceLongitude = varPlace.geometry.location.lng();
```

This produces all values except the `varPlaceID` variable. I am not sure if it is possible to obtain the `place_id` from the `address_components` or in another manner.

Thanks for any help.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Yj5h/1457/) try this,

```
 var varPlaceID = varPlace.place_id;
```

Check Your `street_number` path `varPlace.address_components street_number`

```
   "result" : { 
     "address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "48",
        "short_name" : "48",
        "types" : [ "street_number" ]
     } // I deleted Other
  ], 
  "place_id" : "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4"
```

just call like this `varPlace.place_id`,